# Incorrect use of "do..while" method

Tags: android, do-while

I'm trying to make a repeating loop to display increasing numbers in a single textview.

The general idea is this

```
....
int rep = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Layout);

   do { meth(); } while (rep < 11);

   }


      private void meth() {
      final TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tex );

      String srep = Integer.toString(rep);
      textv.setText(srep);

      if(rep <11) { rep = rep +1; }
                          }
     ....
```

The idea is to display the numbers 1 to 10 in the textview textv ONE BY ONE on screen. But when I ran it, it just shows 10. I'm tried to put in a CountDownTimer inside meth() and also inside the do {} loop but it just crashes the program.

Would appreciate if anyone can point me the right way of doing this.

Comment: why do you create TextView in meth? Do it before your cycle.

Comment: it's because the increment from 1 to 10 occurs in less than a second

Comment: As i understood you need sleep(1000); or something like this in do body.

Comment: You can put some pause in each increment using sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private class MethTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    do { meth(); SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    } while (rep < 11);
     return "";
 }
}
```

And call from onCreate() like this:

```
new MethTask().execute("");
```

Comment: Just tried it putting the line inside the do{} i.e. do{SystemClock.sleep(1000); meth(); }while .... On clicking to the activity, the screen goes black for 10s before it displays again showing only the number 10. I think it actually 'slept' 10 seconds until the cycle ran to the end before displaying it.

Comment: you should call meth() in an AsyncTask and call that AsyncTask from your onCreate().

Comment: I'm not familiar with AsnycTask, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you cannot run this code into oncreate otherwise you won't see anything since onCreate is run before the activity is rendered.
So what you should do is first create a CountownTimer, start it in the onStart method this way:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    startCountDown();
}, 1000);
```

This way you will be sure the activity is displayed

**UPDATE**
If you use `CountownTimer` there is no need to call sleep or other similar methods

Comment: I've tried CountDownTimer within the meth(); method with the text shown onFinish. There is a delay, but after the initial delay, only 10 is shown. I've also tried CountDownTimer inside the do{} loop. That method just crashes the app.